# ODP.Net Ora-6553 pls-752 :Table function fnXXXXX is in inconsistent state , How to avoid?

Tags: c#, oracle, odp.net

I get the error ODP.Net exception Ora-6553 pls-752 :Table function ftRoutineSchema('package','routinename') after compiling a Oracle package.

The function ftRoutineSchema('x','y') accesses USER_ARGUMENT table to retrieve parameter information to construct  command.parameters.

How can I avoid this ?

```
 function ftRoutineSchema(pkg varchar2,Routine varchar2) return  tblRoutineSchema  PIPELINED is 
      x recRoutineSchema;
       pkN  varchar2(100);
   rtN  varchar2(100);
   Begin 

     FOR Y in ( Select Argument_Name  ColumnName
                      ,Data_type      DataType
                      ,Position       ColumnOrder
                      ,In_out         Direction
                      ,Data_length    SSize 
                   from   user_ARGUMENTS 
                      where  package_Name=Upper(pkg) 
                         and object_name=Upper(Routine) order by position 

                         ) 
     LOOP
       PIPE ROW(Y);
     END LOOP;

     Return;  
   End;
```

Comment: It's an Oracle plsql error not ODP's. Can you show us `fnXXXXX` ? is it a pipelined function ? did you change something in the DB, ie drop the schema type you're using or something ?

Comment: Included the code in Q: and note that I answered my own Q.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok folks, sorry again:
I had the package compiled on debug mode, after recompiling none debug. things are ok.